# what does "draft-free" mean?

Tags: baking

Almost every bread recipe I came across says to let the dough proof in a draft-free place. I was wondering what does "draft-free" actually mean? Looking at the dictionary, the closest thing related is something about air current and I'm not so sure about that. 
Thank you

Comment: Easy access to draft could also result in drunk bakers, and thus have a negative effect on their break-baking skills.

Comment: @thrig it also keeps the baker apprentices from being conscripted and sent off to other lands.

Answer (score 25):

It is related to air current. A draft is a localised current of air, usually indoors, the kind that might leak through a door left ajar.

Bread recipes advise using a draft free place for rising A) to prevent poorly covered dough from drying out and B) to make sure the temperature remains warm enough for the quick rise most simple recipes call for.